# glGetShaderInfoLog returning error 1282

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I'm trying to get a shaders info log and the function keeps failing to write into the InfoLog char * buffer. The function is returning error 1282 when i call glGetError right after the glGetShaderInfoLog call. OpenGL error 1282 is associated with GL_INVALID_VALUE or GL_INVALID_OPERATION which both have to do with the shader object not being correct, but to my knowledge I'm creating the shader correctly.

[Docs](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetShaderInfoLog.xhtml)

```
GLuint
OpenGLCreateShader(void *ShaderContents, uint32 ShaderType)
{
    GLuint Result = glCreateShader(ShaderType);

    glShaderSource(Result, 1, (GLchar **)&ShaderContents , 0);
    glCompileShader(Result);

    GLint CompileStatus;
    glGetShaderiv(Result, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &CompileStatus);

    if(CompileStatus == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint InfoLogLength;
        glGetShaderiv(Result, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);

        if(InfoLogLength > 1)
        {
            GLchar *InfoLog = (GLchar *)malloc(InfoLogLength + 1);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(Result, InfoLogLength, &InfoLogLength, InfoLog);
            OutputDebugString(InfoLog);
            free(InfoLog);
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO(zak): Logging
        }
    }


    return(Result);
}
```

Comment: "*OpenGL error 1282 is associated with GL_INVALID_VALUE or GL_INVALID_OPERATION*" The number you're printing is the value of the enum. And the [enum for that value is `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Error). There's no "or" here.

Comment: @NicolBolas Whoops, sorry must've read some false information. So its saying my shader is not a shader object, when it obviously is because i generated it right there.

Comment: And if you call `glGetError()` immediately *before* `glGetShaderInfoLog()`, it does not return an error?

Comment: @RetoKoradi No, there is no error returned if i call glGetError() before glGetShaderInfoLog()

Comment: What's the value of `Result`?

Comment: what is the value of ShaderType?